# Difference between UIView.layoutMargins and AlignmentRect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I'm figuring out (again) how to set the margin for a custom UIView instance. From what I recall I had to set the AlignmentRect via the alignmentRectInsets method. But that did not worked with auto layout. 
Searching on google I found that there is another property called layoutMargins.

So the question is what does layoutMargins and alignmentRect do ? Do they affect each other? Totally different things ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`layoutMargins` determines how things inside of the view are positioned with auto layout. Usually this is used to keep objects a specific distance away from the edges of the view.

`alignmentRectInsets` is for telling objects outside of your custom view how they should align with it. For example, you might have a view with a wavy or angled top. Aligning other objects with the top of the view may not look quite right, so you might set an inset on the top alignment to compensate.

You probably care about the `layoutMargins`. I've never actually seen anyone use `alignmentRectInsets`.